# Changing Dates so They Are Within Business Hours

Tags: javascript, datetime, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

In a JavaScript step in Pentaho Data Integration, I want calculate the time in hours which passes between one date and another.

After following along with this [this blog post](http://rion.io/2014/06/20/calculating-business-hours-in-javascript/), I realize that I need to adjust the startDate and endDate values in the function below which fall outside business hours so that they're within business hours so the function doesn't return zero.  The dates are in the format 09/27/2018 18:54:55.

Here's my attempt so far:

```
var Approve_Gap;
var created_at_copy;
var approved_at_copy1;


// Function that accepts two parameters and calculates
// the number of hours worked within that range
function workingHoursBetweenDates(startDate, endDate) {  
    // Store minutes worked
    var minutesWorked = 0;

    // Validate input
    if (endDate < startDate) { return 0; }

    // Loop from your Start to End dates (by hour)
    var current = startDate;

    // Define work range
    var workHoursStart = 8;
    var workHoursEnd = 17;
    var includeWeekends = true;

    // bring dates into business hours

    if(current.getHours() > workHoursEnd) {
        current = current - (current.getHours() - workHoursEnd);
    }

    else if(current.getHours() < workHoursStart) {
        current = current + (workHoursStart - current.getHours()) 
    }

    if(endDate.getHours() > workHoursEnd) {
        endDate = endDate - (endDate.getHours() - workHoursEnd);
    }

    else if(endDate.getHours() < workHoursStart) {
        endDate = endDate + (workHoursStart - endDate.getHours()) 
    }

    // Loop while currentDate is less than end Date (by minutes)
    while(current <= endDate){   

        // Is the current time within a work day (and if it 
        // occurs on a weekend or not)          
        if(current.getHours() >= workHoursStart && current.getHours() < workHoursEnd && (includeWeekends ? current.getDay() !== 0 && current.getDay() !== 6 : true)){
              minutesWorked++;
        }

        // Increment current time
        current.setTime(current.getTime() + 1000 * 60);
    }

    // Return the number of hours
    return minutesWorked / 60;

}


Approve_Gap = workingHoursBetweenDates(created_at_copy, approved_at_copy1);
```

Comment: Are startDate and endDate on the same day ?

Comment: And what does not work in your attempt ?

Comment: Sometimes the startDate and endDate are on the same day, but not always.

Comment: current.setHours(9);
    current.setMinutes(1);

Comment: current = dateAdd(current, "hh", (current.getHours() - workHoursEnd)) //a Pentaho function

Comment: //and current = current + (workHoursStart - current.getHours()); //I also tried multiplying the part in parenthesis to get it in milliseconds.

Comment: All those attempts don't change the didn't the date values, even though I'm not getting error messages.

Answer (score 0):

I got the dates into business hours by adjusting copies of the dates as shown below:

```
if(created_at_copy.getHours() >= workHoursEnd) {
    created_at_copy.setDate(created_at_copy.getDate() + 1);
    created_at_copy.setHours(8);
    created_at_copy.setMinutes(0);
    created_at_copy.setSeconds(0);

} else if(created_at_copy.getHours() < workHoursStart) {
    created_at_copy.setHours(8);
    created_at_copy.setMinutes(0);
    created_at_copy.setSeconds(0);

}

if(approved_at_copy1.getHours() >= (workHoursEnd)) {
    approved_at_copy1.setDate(approved_at_copy1.getDate() + 1);
    approved_at_copy1.setHours(8);
    approved_at_copy1.setMinutes(0);
    created_at_copy.setSeconds(0);

} else if(approved_at_copy1.getHours() < workHoursStart) {
    approved_at_copy1.setHours(8);
    approved_at_copy1.setMinutes(0);
    created_at_copy.setSeconds(0);
}
```